# I need to capitalize the next string css

Tags: css, reactjs, string, styles, uppercase

I need to capitalize the next string css

1- item

```
.table-generic p::first-letter {
text-transform: uppercase;}
```

How can I do this with that number at the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that specific case, you could just use `text-transform: capitalize` on the element itself (instead of the `first-letter` pseudo-element).

```css
p {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<p>1- item</p>
```

Maybe you have other requirements or restrictions, but they are not apparent from your question.